# Remove space between images in tables for email newsletter

Tags: html, css, newsletter

I need help in removing the space between those images in the table.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8EHED/81/

```
         <tr>
            <td width="600" align="center" valign="top">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="480" align="left" valign="bottom" style="background-color:#fee100; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                               <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" style="margin-left:25px"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="120" style="background-color:#fee100;">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/120x50" style="margin-right:25px; display:block">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>        
            </td>
        </tr>
```

As you can see in the fiddle I used table inside of another table because I want to align everything to center using the second table that has an width of 600px.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which space exactly?

Comment: Looks good to me. Specifically what space?

Comment: Space between images, but the issue was solved, by the answer I received.

Answer (score 4):

You need usually to reset, `vertical-align` to `top` or `bottom` or in your case  `display` to `block` for `img` .

```
    td img {
      display:block;
      }
```

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: ;
}
img {
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; background-color:#ffffff;">
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="100%" align="center">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; padding:0;">
          <tr>
            <td width="600" align="center" valign="top">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <tr>
                  <td width="480" align="left" valign="bottom" style="background-color:#fee100; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" alt="PSNY" style="margin-left:25px" />
                  </td>
                  <td width="120" style="background-color:#fee100;">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x50" style="margin-right:25px; display:block">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="600" align="center" valign="top">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                <tr>
                  <td width="150">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50" style="margin-left:25px; display:block">
                  </td>
                  <td style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <h2 style="font-family:Times New Roman, Times; font-size:24px; color:#000200; text-align: center;"><span style="border-bottom:1px solid #000200; padding-bottom: 5px;">My Title</span></h2> 

                  </td>
                  <td width="150">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/120x50" style="margin-right:25px; float:right; display:block">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8EHED/83/